# Can't get jQuery clockpicker plugin to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the jQuery plugin clockpicker to work.

I have the relevant bootstrap and plugin CSS files linked at the top:

```
<link href="./stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./stylesheets/jquery-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I also have the scripts included in this order:

```
<script jquery>
    <script src="./javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascripts/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
        });
```

So there's no dependency issues.

I also have the html set up as intended in the tutorial

```
<div class="input-group clockpicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30">
</div>
```

However, when clicking on it, nothing happens! I've checked console log errors, and there's no relevant errors. I'm assuming this isn't relevant:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you see any console errors in the browser??

Comment: Just for the record, the GET fails on fonts and such are not relevant here. A failure on one of the script libraries would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure including jquery JS script file before bootstrap js script file, such as

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
```

**JS**

```
var clock = $('.form-control');
clock.clockpicker({
    autoclose: true
});

// minutes
clock.clockpicker('show').clockpicker('toggleView', 'minutes');

// hours
// clock.clockpicker('show').clockpicker('toggleView', 'hours');
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ch7af2n/3/)**

Comment: Updated js code, it should be worked and can find example in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6ch7af2n/3/ as well.